# Python shorthand for tensor product (Kronecker product)

Tags: programming, linear-algebra, qutip

When using `numpy` or `tensorflow` in Python, we can simply write

```
C = A @ B
```

for matrix multiplication `C = np.matmul(A,B)`. I wonder if there is a shorthand for tensor product (Kronecker product), $C=A\otimes B$ . Now I can only do this by using `np.kron(A, B)`  or using qutip `qutip.tensor(A, B)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python currently doesn't support an operator for Kronecker products. Note how the `@` symbol works: when you write the statement `A @ B`, Python$^1$ checks the objects `A` and `B` for a `__matmul__` method and then returns `A.__matmul__(B)`. But there's no built-in operator that corresponds to something like a `__kron__` method.

If you really want this functionality, one way might be to change how the `*` operator works by redefining `__mul__` (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252765/overriding-other-rmul-with-your-classs-mul) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229953/array-and-rmul-operator-in-python-numpy)) to perform a kronecker product, so that calling `A * B` would return `np.kron(A, B)`. However this could end up being very confusing for yourself and others reading your code.

---

$^1$ as of Python 3.5, see PEP 465: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/